# не получаеться передать текстовый файл через ACTION.SEND

Tags: android, android-intent

у меня есть на телефоне файл.txt я хочу его передать с помощью Intent.ACTION_SEND в текст письма но столкнулся с проблемой
в тексте письма пусто

```
ArrayList<String> s = StorageUtils.readInternalFile(getApplicationContext());
//это мы получаем данные с файла на телефоне
```

а вот и весь код

```
 private void sendCall() {
   ArrayList<String> s = StorageUtils.readInternalFile(getApplicationContext());
    Log.e("MainActivity", "sendCall" + s);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, s);
//        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s); 
    intent.setT ype("text/plain");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: А если заменить тип посылаемого на вот это: `emailIntent.setType("text/html");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Intent по ключам `EXTRA_SUBJECT` и `EXTRA_TEXT` нельзя помещать списки, [только строки](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_TEXT), так что должно быть так:

```
 private void sendCall() {
     String text = TextUtils.join("\n", StorageUtils.readInternalFile(getApplicationContext()));

     Log.e("MainActivity", "sendCall" + s);
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text); 
     intent.setType("text/plain");
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

у вас же закомментирована строка с назначением текста письма...

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s);
```